# Creating CASE statement with Calculated Column

Tags: 2010, calculated-column, custom-list

I am using SharePoint 2010.

I added a new Column and made it a Calculated Column.

Now I need to place a CASE statement in my Formula. Something like this...

```
CASE when [Region1] = 'A' and [Region2] = 'B' THEN
     'NO'
     when [Region1] = 'C' and [Region2] = 'D' THEN
     'YES'
     else
     'N/A'
END
```

So the value of my Calculated Column will be either YES or NO

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rewrite your formula with `if`-statements and nest them, something like this:

```
=if(AND([Region1]="A",[Region2]="B"),"NO",if(AND([Region1]="C",[Region2]="D"),"YES","N/A"))
```

The first `if` does the first test, if that statement doesn't hold: use the second `if` (nested in the first if).

Comment: isn't the `;` the correct parameters separator?

Comment: Sadly it depends on the language you are using.

Comment: @Dribbel really sadly, here in Brazil the separator is `;` it created a lot of difficult to me.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use IF statements, look at this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071.aspx) or this [Office document](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/CH010065006.aspx) for references.  It also helps to mock it up in Excel and then copy/paste it into the calculated column.

Edit: just about had it figured out and Dribble beat me to the formula, nested Ifs which can go up to 7 deep.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of CASE in SharePoint is CHOOSE, but it is not very flexible (you need to resort to tricks to convert your cases into numbers). Usually nested ifs work better.